# Al compilar la app obtengo el error: Could not resolve all files for configuration

Tags: flutter

Al tratar de compilar mi aplicacion obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+.
>   Required by:
>   project :app > project :location
>   > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
>   > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
>   > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 40s
> [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Actualiza tu `build.gradle` con lo siguiente:

Cambia esto

```dart
    dependencies {
            com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2
    }
```

por lo siguiente

```
    dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        }
```

También actualiza el `distributionUrl` del archivo `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

```dart
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Para este error pueden ser varias causas, una de ellas es precisamente la que se describe en tu mensaje de error:

> Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Esto puede ser un problema temporal indicando que el servidor con estas bibliotecas se encuentra inactivo.

de hecho también indica:

> Gradle arrojó un error al descargar artefactos de la red. Volviendo a
> intentar descargar...

Otra causa es que estas usando versiones dinamicas (usando +) lo cual no recomienda Google, te sugiero cambiar:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+
```

definiendo una versión de esta forma:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0
```